# Xcode 6, print the value of a define in the LLDB console?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, lldb

It is possible to check the value of a DEFINE using a command in the lldb window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean C preprocessor defines?  While there is a format for recording preprocessor defines & macros in DWARF, which is the default debug information format for gcc & clang and the only one lldb supports, for most substantial programs the resultant increase in debug info size is so great that it really isn't practical to use it.  gcc does emit it (though doing so is not the default) and last time I played around with it gdb had spotty but functional support for macro information .  But clang has never supported writing DWARF macro information, and lldb doesn't support it either.